# Jackson JAXB support doesnt marshall objects inside objects?

Tags: java, jackson, jaxb

I'm having trouble with Jacksons JAXB support, it doesn't seem to marshall objects inside other objects?

This is my code (simplified, not getters/setters):

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "identifiableObject" )
class IdentifiableObject {
  @XmlAttribute
  Integer id;

  @XmlElement
  String name;
}

@XmlRootElement( name = "a" )
class A extends IdentifiableObject {}

@XmlRootElement( name = "b" )
class B extends IdentifiableObject {
  @XmlElement
  @XmlJavaType( IdentifiableObjectXmlAdapter.class )
  A a;
}
```

When I marshall this using JAXB i have no troubles, it works fine. But when I try to marshall it with Jackson, it seems like it only sees the annotations directly on the object, so it marshalls it to be:

```
{ id: 1,   name: "name",   a: {} }
```

If I add `@JsonProperty` to my IdentifiableObject it works fine, but I was hoping to not do that.. and if I do, it doesnt seem like `@XmlJavaAdapter` works anymore on the property (not so strange, since I have `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` first in my introspector pair)

Anyways.. is it possible to:

(a) Have Jacksons JAXB support do deep marshalling of objects? (it works fine with the JacksonAnnotationIntrospector as mentioned)

(b) Is there something similar to `XmlAdapter` for Jackson that I could plug in?

UPDATE:
To clarify, my expected output was:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "b object",
  a: {
    id: 2, 
    name: "a object"
  }
}
```

This is the default behavior when using JAXB marshalling, but not when doing the same for JSON (through JAXB annotation introspector)

(a) My current solution here is to add `@JsonProperty` just about everywhere, so that the jackson annotation introspector will be used instead (since in my pair, its the primary introspector), and that works OK, but then I have so many annotations on each getter.

(b) I tried using `@JsonSerialize` here using a custom `JsonSerializer`, but even if I downcast the object here `(IdentifiableObject) a;` it still "sees" the old version of a, and marshalls everything on it.

--
Morten

Comment: I am not 100% sure I know what expected output would be. Could you add JSON you expect as output? Is this about name used for properties, or about existence of a property?